# How do streaming aggregators like Reelgood search and launch?

Tags: algorithm, search, streaming

I've been thinking about it and I can't seem to figure it out. Streaming services like Hulu, HBO Now, and the likes, don't have an API.

How do streaming aggregators manage to search shows across all of these services, and then launch them from a specific user's account? Would a regular developer be able to create a streaming aggregator with just openly-available resources?

Thanks in advance!